# Как добавить новую запись в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть следующий pandas `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['labels', 'texts'])
```

Как добавить новую запись в этот `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Эффективнее собрать все данные в список списков и создать DataFrame целиком:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['labels', 'texts'])
```

Чтобы добавить одну строку:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = [label, text]
```